# Doble animación CSS

Tags: html, css, animación

Estoy intentando que un mismo objeto tenga 2 animaciones. La primera animación, que vaya de 10 a 100 (por ejemplo) y que esto se repita 2 veces. Cuando se acabe esa animación, que empiece la otra que al 100% del ancho vaya cambiando de color por infinito.

Lo que tengo es esto, pero no sale como quiero:

```css
#AnimacionTitulo {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #CCBDFB;
  color: FloralWhite;
  font-weight: bold;
  animation: AnimacionTitulo 1.5s 2.5, cambioRGB 10s infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes AnimacionTitulo {
  50% { width: 100%; }
}

@keyframes cambioRGB {
  60%  {background-color: #31e4a6;}
  70%  {background-color: #6de431;}
  80%  {background-color: #e4a331;}
  90%  {background-color: #772bec;}
  100% {background-color: DarkSlateBlue;}
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="AnimacionTitulo">
      <h1>Buenas tardes</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Siento que estoy muy muy cerca, pero no logro dar con lo que me falta. La animación en si se hace bien, pero quiero que el cambio de color se haga cuando la primera animación termine.

Tampoco entiendo por qué van a distintas velocidades el cambio de color...

Comment: Un apaño que acabo de descubrir, es poniéndole a la segunda animación que dure más segundos, pero seguramente haya otra forma menos chapucera

Comment: Estás muy cerca. Redacto respuesta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lo primero que haría sería independizar una animación de otra, para así poder dar propiedades a cada animación independientemente.

El problema de esto es que un mismo elemento no puede recibir dos animaciones por lo que la animación de desplegar y plegar se la di al `<div>` contenedor y el cambio de color al `<h1>`.

Luego, a través de `animation-delay` calcular lo que tarda en ejecutarse la primera animación para después lanzar la segunda.

```css
#AnimacionTitulo {
  width: 200px;
}

h1 {
  background-color: #CCBDFB;
  color: FloralWhite;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.desplegar {
  animation-name: AnimacionTitulo;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: 2.5;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.cambia_color {
    animation-name: cambioRGB;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-delay: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes AnimacionTitulo {
  50% { width: 100%; }
}

@keyframes cambioRGB {
  60%  {background-color: #31e4a6;}
  70%  {background-color: #6de431;}
  80%  {background-color: #e4a331;}
  90%  {background-color: #772bec;}
  100% {background-color: DarkSlateBlue;}
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
      <div id="AnimacionTitulo" class="desplegar">
        <h1 class="cambia_color">Buenas tardes</h1>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Con el shortHand de CSS**

```css
#AnimacionTitulo {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #CCBDFB;
  color: FloralWhite;
  font-weight: bold;
  animation: AnimacionTitulo 1.5s 2.5, cambioRGB 10s infinite 3.75s;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes AnimacionTitulo {
  50% { width: 100%; }
}

@keyframes cambioRGB {
  60%  {background-color: #31e4a6;}
  70%  {background-color: #6de431;}
  80%  {background-color: #e4a331;}
  90%  {background-color: #772bec;}
  100% {background-color: DarkSlateBlue;}
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div id="AnimacionTitulo">
      <h1>Buenas tardes</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Con la notación abreviada de `animation` se le podría pasar el `delay` como parámetro.